# Unit testing a function with assertions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have the following assert macro definition:

```
#define ASSERT_IF(expression)   \
    if (expression) {           \
        __debugbreak();         \
    }
```

And the following function that uses the assert macro:

```
std::string createFilename(std::string_view name, std::string_view extension) {
    ASSERT_IF(name.empty() || extension.empty());

    std::string result;
    result += name;
    result += '.';
    result += extension;
    return result;
}
```

How can I unit test such functions where input arguments are verified using assert macro? Or is there some kind of pattern that could be used to verify the input and then be able to unit test that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easily actually, if you can use [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/assertions.md#death). If you want to check that your program crashes on empty filename, simple death test does the job:

```
TEST(xxxDeathTest, yyy)
{
    ASSERT_DEATH(createFilename("", ""), "");
}
```

By `__debugbreak` I guess you are on Windows. If you could use Linux, then you could be more specific and use `testing::KilledBySignal` to check that your program was killed by `SIGTRAP`.

Comment: Would it actually work with __debugbreak?

Comment: Yeah, I copy-pasted your code and it runs out of the box on my windows.

Comment: With and without debugger attached?

Comment: @Jarod42 surprisingly on Linux (substituting `__debugbreak();` with `raise(SIGTRAP);`) the test is still passing and exiting normally under gdb. I don't know how it will behave with visual studio. And without DEATH assertion gdb will break. Fork magic.

Comment: Note: death tests should have suite name that ends in `DeathTest`, per the strong recommendation in [documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#death-test-naming). In this case, `TEST(xxxDeathTest, yyy)`